# Android 6.0 x86_64 bit boot stuck at root@x86_64:/ on Windows Hyper-V

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, android-x86, vm

I have been trying to start up and Android x86 (64-bit) on Hyper-V using the latest edition available from http://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-6-0-r2http

I have installed it with GRUB and created a bootable Partition during installation. Format drive to ext4.

Every time I try to run the VM I am presented with the following image
[image]

and it doesn't proceed to boot to the android screen. Anyone have an idea how to fix? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What RAM size have you selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default screen resolution /color depth is not work. Need to be changed. A guide could be find here:

[How to Install Android x86 4.4 R2 on Hyper-V – Part 2: Configuration, Screen resolution and Network (Jan 2015)](http://luisrato.azurewebsites.net/2015/01/02/how-to-install-android-x86-4-4-r2-on-hyper-v-part-2-configuration-screen-resolution-and-network-jan-2015/)

Comment: The screen resolution seemed to fix it, but now when I get to the initial page for setting up Android, when I click the arrow to proceed with setup, the VM then bootloops back to the android loading screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> I have extracted the guide below from the article which made reference
>   to remixos on hyper-v, however the procedure is the same for any
>   android x86 installation:

**Install Android x86 on Hyper-V virtual machine**

Installation to Hyper-V virtual machine is a bit tricky, but achievable.

- First of all, create Generation 1 VM with at least 6 Gb HDD.
- After creation of VM do not power on it.
- Connect created VHD disk to any windows machine (**Disk Management -> Right Click -> Attach VHD**)
- **Initialize it as MBR disk**.
- Format it in FAT32 file system.
- Detach VHD.
- Boot VM with Legacy ISO. **Do not choose Resident or Guest mode**

**During boot up;**

- Press TAB button. Edit your boot string to:

`/kernel initrd=initrd.img root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=android_x86 androidboot.selinux=permissive quiet INSTALL=1 nomodeset vga=785`

- You can replace 785 with any 16bit (or 24bit) color depth code. More codes can be found at http://pierre.baudu.in/other/grub.vga.modes.html
- Chose sda1 partition (`vfat system`)
- Do not format it.
- Chose yes for GRUB installation.
- Skip EFI GRUB2 installation.
- Choose yes for making system directory read-write.
- Choose yes for creating user data image.
- Enter size of `data.img`. Maximum is 2047 because we formatted our dist to FAT32 file system.
  You can run you Android-x86. It’ll take a while, do not panic.
- Configure it as you wish.

**After completion;**

- The last thing you need to do is eject ISO from VM and edit created GRUB entries.

  - Shutdown your VM and eject ISO.
  - Once again attach VHD to Windows machine.
  - Edit `\grub\menu.lst`

You need to delete extra digits after kernel path, for example if you used `vga=785` previously you need to replace `kernel785` with `kernel` . Also you need to add desired vga mode again. So your menu.lst should look like:

```
default=0
timeout=6
splashimage=/grub/android-x86.xpm.gz
root (hd0,0)
title Android-x86
kernel /android-2016-01-14/kernel vga=785 quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=android_x86 androidboot.selinux=permissive nomodeset SRC=/android-2016-01-14
initrd /android-2016-01-14/initrd.img
title Android-x86 (Debug mode)
kernel /android-2016-01-14/kernelvga=785 root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=android_x86 androidboot.selinux=permissive nomodeset DEBUG=2 SRC=/android-2016-01-14
initrd /android-2016-01-14/initrd.img
title Android-x86 (Debug nomodeset)
kernel /android-2016-01-14/kernel vga=785 nomodeset root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=android_x86 androidboot.selinux=permissive nomodeset DEBUG=2 SRC=/android-2016-01-14
initrd /android-2016-01-14/initrd.img
title Android-x86 (Debug video=LVDS-1:d)
kernel /android-2016-01-14/kernel vga=785 video=LVDS-1:d root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=android_x86 androidboot.selinux=permissive nomodeset DEBUG=2 SRC=/android-2016-01-14
initrd /android-2016-01-14/initrd.img
```

- Detach VHD and boot your VM.

**You should now get past the screen android x86**

(*Unfortunately couldn't upload images since I used RemixOS instead of androidx86*)

Sincerest acknowledgements go to:

[Install RemixOS on Hyper-V virtual machine](http://trukhanov.com/2016/01/install-remixos-on-hyper-v-virtual-machine/)