# Android x86 Stuck at A N D R O I D x86_64:/

Tags: 7.1-nougat, android-x86

I downloaded Android x86 7.1 from Android x86 Project website. I have made a Virtual Machine for it in the VMware Player. It's stuck at

[image: screenshot]

VMware settings are as follows: 
 1 Core, 
 2048 RAM, 
 20GB IDE Virtual Drive.

---

PC Specs: 
Intel Core i5-2400 
4GB of DDR3 RAM
250GB HDD // if that helps :P

Comment: Here is how I fixed the problem: [How to start GUI from command line in Android-x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223402/how-to-start-gui-from-command-line-in-android-x86/60278101#60278101).

Other answers may help also.

Comment: [Android 6.0 x86_64 bit boot stuck at root@x86_64:/ on Windows Hyper-V](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/171562/218526)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run Android without installation:

From the grub menu after booting the installation media, choose advanced options then:

"Live CD VESA mode - no GPU hardware acceleration"

and if you already installed android and you want to boot it, in the grub menu press 'e' to edit the boot command, press 'e' again to edit the first command which starts with "kernel".
 Append this:

```
 nomodeset
```

to the and of the command and press Enter to save, finally press 'b' to boot from the modified command and it will boot up successfully.

I tried this with CM 14.1 and Android 7.1 images and it works after I had the same problem with VMWare Workstation 14.