# Android-x86 stuck at black screen and a static underscore _

Tags: android-x86

I have a very similar problem to e.g. [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196389/android-x86-stuck-at-a-n-d-r-o-i-d-x86-64).

I installed Android-x86 on a partition on my Acer Aspire Switch 10E next to Windows.

I added Grub as trusted boot option in the UEFI and let Secure Boot **enabled**.

Using this I can completely boot and reboot into e.g. Android x86 version 8.1-R2

**But** the problem is: in this version my Realtek RTL8723BS is not supported -> No WiFi/Bluetooth!

---

So I worked my way back to older versions (I need at least Android 6.0). Using CM 14.1-R2 and Androidx86 7.1-R2 I have a strange behavior:

Right after the installation if I select "Run Android" everything works fine, it boots normal, WiFi/Bluetooth everything fine!

But I am not able in any way getting it to run again after a reboot. It is forever stuck on a black screen with only displaying a fix (not blinking)

```
_
```

---

I already searched for two days and tried a lot of parameters and settings in the Grub entry like `nomodeset`, `xforcevesa` etc ... nothing worked so far.

I also tried both 32bit and 64bit versions (the device is 64bit) but it made no difference.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong or why it boots all fine the first time if not going for the reboot but directly to the `Run Android` option. So I guess it can not be due to unsupported hardware since the system basically works ... I just can not boot into it anymore after shutting down / reboot.

---

Does anyone have a solution for that?

---

**Note: I am not speaking about a Virtual Machine here!**

Answer (score 4):

I found disabling 3D acceleration and setting the graphic controller to VBoxVGA solves the issue.

Comment: As I mentioned back then .. it wasn't a virtual machine! It is Android flashed to an actual tablet hardware device ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. When you see the selection, press E on the keyboard (for editing). [ You will see a line after it ]
2. Replace `quiet` with `nomodeset xforcevesa`. [ Then press B for boot ]
3. Your Android will boot correctly only one time. [ Android will start running ]
4. Now press Alt + F1 to launch console.
5. Type: `mkdir /mnt/sda`
6. Type: `mount /dev/block/sda1 /mnt/sda`
7. Type: `vi /mnt/sda/grub/menu.lst` [ You can search use of vi on Google ]
8. Replace `quiet` with `nomodeset xforcevesa`.
9. Press Esc, and `:wq`
10. Type reboot. [ Your Android will work fine ]

Answer (score 0):

When you change the internal frame where the UEFI firmware settings to the EFI framework setting, change the boot order.

You have to make a small partition for grub, go back, and change it back. Otherwise, it won't boot the second time.

Comment: Sorry I fear I didn't fully understand what you mean. Could you explain step by step what I have to do?