# Android x86 Oreo (8.1) stuck at _ (underscore) after GRUB

Tags: 8.1-oreo, android-x86, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Android x86 on virtual machine in VirtualBox 6.0.

The image I've downloaded is `android-x86_64-8.1-r2.iso` from [android-x86.org](https://android-x86.org)

The installation process I've followed is similar to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4Bw2jeYwZg)

But when I'm reaching GRUB boot option selection and choose `Android-x86 8.1-r2`, it stops working and hangs on underscore before "Android" logo, which never shows to me.

[image: Final result of installation for now is underscore screen]

I've tried [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144535/android-x86-marshmallow-not-booting-on-virtualbox-and-vmware-workstation) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088222/boot-process-of-android-installed-in-virtualbox-seems-to-get-stuck/1088231) fix, but it didn't work. Also, there's [a post regarding similar issue on Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214059/android-x86-stuck-at), but it never was answered.

Stack, what do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `VM Settings` > `Display` > `Graphics Controller` to `VBoxVGA`. Unless done so, Android x86 won't launch.

More [here](https://www.android-x86.org/documentation/virtualbox.html).