# Android-x86 8.1 in VMWare Workstation doesn't show GUI

Tags: android-x86

I installed android-x86-8.1-r2.iso 64 bit version in VMWare Workstation 15.5.0 under Win10x64 1903.

It starts into the linux command line prompt, and I tried Alt+Fx, there is no GUI. I tried all four boot menu(normal/debug/debug nomodeset/debug VIDEO=LVDS...), all the same.

Comment: The solution is like @xavier_fakerat's answer in https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171562/android-6-0-x86-64-bit-boot-stuck-at-rootx86-64-on-windows-hyper-v

Answer (score 3):

To switch to GUI, please ensure that you have **3D acceleration turned on in VMWare Machine Settings.**

If you still cannot see the GUI, try **Alt+F7**

Comment: Now the command line promt will continue to become a black screen with a non-flashing cursor, Alt+Fx has no response. What possiblly next?

Comment: Have you ensured that your virtual machine has been allotted adequate  graphics memory?

Comment: 4GB RAM with 1GB GMEM for the VM, not working. Set the VDisplay to 1024*768 not working too. 4K60 monitor driven by NV1650 GPU.

Comment: Try running 'startx' in terminal.

Comment: It turns out that it not the GPU problem, it is still the menu.lst problem which I used before for Andorid-x86 4.2

Comment: I have also encountered this problem but managed to solve it by selecting the graphics card manually in VMWare mahcine settings.